# Google Places API giving exception invalid Api key for android app

Tags: android, google-places-api

In my android app i have added google api v2 for showing map and this is working fine,now i want to use Places API for show near by location.I have added service for it and use below url

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=22.7253,75.8655&radius=500&sensor=true&types=bar&key=mykey
```

but it giving response-

```
{  "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this       API key.",
     "html_attributions" : [],
     "results" : [],
     "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

so why suce error is returns.where i am missing.
Thanks in advance.